# How to debug Cloud Run (Visual Studio Code) Local running problems?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, local

i'm working with Google Cloud Run and Visual Studio Code. I'm trying to build a simple Flask service and trying to test it locally in the "emulator" on my Win10 laptop (by choosing the 'Cloud Run: Run/Debug Locally' task) and when I do that it seems to start trying but then always fails with the error below.. How do I mitigate such a message, as it's not very informative.. ! Thanks.

```
Deploy started
Deploy completed

Status check started
Resource pod/rbfcloudrun-7875f79d7-kwmsd status updated to In Progress
Resource deployment/rbfcloudrun status updated to In Progress
Resource pod/rbfcloudrun-7875f79d7-kwmsd status updated to In Progress
Resource pod/rbfcloudrun-7875f79d7-kwmsd status updated to In Progress
Resource deployment/rbfcloudrun status failed with waiting for rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
Status check failed

Update failed with error code STATUSCHECK_CONTAINER_RESTARTING
1/1 deployment(s) failed
Skaffold exited with code 1.
Cleaning up...
Finished clean up.
```

For reference, my dockerfile is something like:

```
FROM python:3
# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True
ENV PORT 8080
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install flask 
RUN pip install gunicorn 

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
# "main:app" - because main.py is the entry file, and app is the name of the webapp instance in that file
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

..my requirements.txt file looks like:

```
Flask==2.0.2
requests==2.26.0
ptvsd==4.3.2 # Required for debugging.
```

Comment: Do you have Docker installed and running on your computer?

Comment: yes i do;   (looks like i now know the reason that it was doing this failure - there were some python errors in the flask/views) - i'd still love to know what you were going to suggest; A common way to CLI into the running docker and check things..?..

Comment: Mmm I tried some time to find something but seems this is not possible for now, not at least in simple way since everything is running with minikube :/